# Mask Street Address - Teradata SQL Assistant

Tags: sql, string, teradata, varchar

Teradata SQL Assistant - Mask/Edit Varchar Address field - (Contains numbers, text, punctuation).

Is there a method to mask/edit street address from

```
12345 Springfield Ave NE
```

to

```
123XX Springfield Ave NE
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you told what "Mask/Edit Varchar Address field" means. Like, is it the name of a dialog window? It might give context to and jog the memory of someone who hasn't used the tool for a while, for example. You can edit the question to add some context. In a question like this, a relevant screenshot might also be useful for getting an answer.

Comment: I'm sure, based on your 1 example, you could probably do it with some sort of substring/concatenation, but we'd need to understand your rules a lot better.

Comment: Looks like you need a `REGEXP_REPLACE`, but this is totally independent of the client used...

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I am a novice user. The 'Mask/Edit Varchar Address Field' refers to the address field/item in a relational database table. After accessing the field (Teradata SQL assistant) I  would like to transform that data so that the information can be used to identify the block on which a person resides without providing their exact address. One possibility might be break apart the address field at the occurrence of each space using substring and then add a random amount between 0-99 to the first 'section' of the substring. I'd handle PO Box/ Lot# separately.